# Send audio from one Pi to another- Same network

Tags: pi-3, networking, audio, connection, streaming

Beginner here.

The Goal:

Send audio source from one Pi to another over the same network.

Both Pi's will have a static IP and will be locked onto each other.

I've attached a diagram for reference.

Thank You guys in advance!

[image]

Comment: Have a look at Pulse Audio, an audio server for Linux. It can send audio over the network to another device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!   Does this server allow me to stream in realtime from one device to another & set up multiple links?

Comment: Look at this http://www.pogo.org.uk/~mark/trx/ It is simple to compile on the Raspberry and has very low latency.

Comment: @user97974 I've been trying to get this going for a week on and off and am having no luck even compiling on my raspberry pis. Can you share some instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the simplest way is to use [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/HomePage):

Install sox on both Pis:

`apt-get install sox`

Lets assume the Pi with the audio source is 198.51.100.2, and the Pi attached to the amplifier is 198.51.100.3

On the source pi (198.51.100.2), make sure you can run ssh without needing a password:

`ssh-copy-id 198.51.100.3`

That's all the set-up done. Now to actually do the record/playing:

`rec -c 1 -t wav - | ssh 198.51.100.3 play -`

How does this work?

The rec command records audio from the default input device (which will be fine unless you have more than one). The audio is then sent down a unix pipe to the ssh command, which sends it over the network to the other Pi and executes the play command.

The -c 1 argument to the rec command says to record only one channel; if you want stereo then use -c 2.

(Note the IP addresses used are from RFC5737 and are for documentation only).

Comment: Nick-    Thanks a ton for all the info, I will try it & follow up....    Does this method allow me to listen in real time?  ( I understand there will be some delay due to size & activity of network.  Also, would I run into any issues if i set up multiple links (Pi-1 stream to Pi-2       Pi-3 stream to Pi-4       Pi-5 stream to Pi-6)

Comment: Thank You so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Implemented it today & it worked like a charm.

Comment: Could you mark the answer as accepted in that case please?